# state pattern C++

Tags: c++, class, virtual, state-pattern

I'm trying to instigate a simple State pattern, after following some of the excellent tutorials here: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

I am half way through this current tutorial, and I am trying to replicate the static instances of each state, by containing them within the base class. However, when it comes to switching states, g++ is throwing this error.

```
   state_test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Introduction::handleinput(Game&, int)’:
state_test.cpp:55:16: error: cannot convert ‘Playing*’ to ‘GameState*’ in assignment
    game.state_ = &GameState::play;
                ^
```

Now, I understand the error involves the conversion of the pointer, but I am really struggling to see how to fix it. As I was following this guys code, I kind of expected it to work, but because he is changing it as he goes along and trying to reinforce best practice, I don't have his complete source code to follow. However, I feel it is important for me to understand the code at this stage, before I move through the rest of the tutorial.

Following is the code I created, attempting to replicate his state system:

```
#include <iostream>

class Game;
class Introduction;
class Playing;

class GameState
{
public:

    static Introduction intro;
    static Playing play;

    virtual ~GameState() {std::cout << "an undefined GameState has been destroyed" << std::endl;}
    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) {}
    virtual void update(Game& game) {}

};

class Game
{
public:

    Game()
    {}
    ~Game()
    {}

    virtual void handleinput(int arbitary)
        {
            state_->handleinput(*this, arbitary);
        }

    virtual void update()
        {
            state_->update(*this);
        }

//private: 
    GameState* state_;
};

class Introduction : public GameState
{
public:

    Introduction()  
    {
        std::cout << "constructed Introduction state" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
        {
            if (arbitary == 1)
            game.state_ = &GameState::play;
        }

    virtual void update(Game& game) {}
};

class Playing : public GameState
{
public:
    Playing()   {std::cout << "constructed Playing state" << std::endl;}

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
        {
            if (arbitary == 0)
            game.state_ = &GameState::intro;
        }

    virtual void update(Game& game) {}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Game thisgame;

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas why my implementation isn't compiling?

EDIT:

So in response to the earlier tutoring, for which I was very grateful, I revised the code. I start by putting it all in separate files, but this was more trouble than it was worth for such a small amount of test code. I simply rewrote one header file which declared the classes, and then defined them in the .cpp file.

Here is the .h file:

```
class Introduction;
class Playing;
class Game;
class GameState;

class GameState
{
    public:

    static Introduction intro;
    static Playing play;

    virtual ~GameState();
    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary);
    virtual void update(Game& game);

};


class Introduction : public GameState
{
public:

    Introduction();

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary); 

    virtual void update(Game& game);

};

class Playing : public GameState
{
public:
    Playing();

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary);

    virtual void update(Game& game);    
};


class Game
{
public:

    Game();

    ~Game();

    virtual void handleinput(int arbitary);

    virtual void update();

    GameState* state_;

};
```

And here is the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "state.h"


GameState::~GameState() 
    {std::cout << "Exiting Game State Instance" << std::endl;}
void GameState::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
    {}
void GameState::update(Game& game) 
    {}



Game::Game()
    {}
Game::~Game()
    {}
void Game::handleinput(int arbitary)
        {
            state_->handleinput(*this, arbitary);
        }

void Game::update()
        {
            state_->update(*this);
        }


Introduction::Introduction()    
    {
        std::cout << "constructed Introduction state" << std::endl;
    }

void Introduction::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
        {
            if (arbitary == 1)
            game.state_ = &GameState::play;
        }

void Introduction::update(Game& game) {}


Playing::Playing()  
        {
            std::cout << "constructed Playing state" << std::endl;
        }

void Playing::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
        {
            if (arbitary == 0)
            game.state_ = &GameState::intro;
        }

void Playing::update(Game& game) {}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Game mygame;
    return 0;
}
```

And I still can't get it to work. The previous error has gone away, but I am struggling to access the static instances of "introduction" and playing inside of the base class. The error thrown is:

```
/tmp/ccH87ioX.o: In function `Introduction::handleinput(Game&, int)':
state_test.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `GameState::play'
/tmp/ccH87ioX.o: In function `Playing::handleinput(Game&, int)':
state_test.cpp:(.text+0x23f): undefined reference to `GameState::intro'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought i had it sussed! So frustrated!

I should add that the answer provided by RustyX does compile, however I have to move the instances of "playing" and "introduction" outside of the class definition, and I can then no longer set them to be static, I believe this is important because I only need one instance of each and I would like them to be initialised as early as possible.

Comment: You might be interested in my [STTCL](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl) framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler reads the file from top to bottom. At the line that contains

```
game.state_ = &GameState::play;
```

he still doesn't know that `Playing` inherits from `GameState`. It only knows that `Playing` is a class that will be declared later.

You should split the class declarations from method implementations. Have all class declarations first and method implementations later. In bigger project you would split them all to individual *.h and *.cpp files and this ordering would happen naturally.

Shortened example:

```
class Playing : public GameState
{
public:
    Playing();

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary);

    virtual void update(Game& game);
};

// Declarations of other classes...


Playing::Playing() {
    std::cout << "constructed Playing state" << std::endl;
}

void Playing::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitrary) {
    if (arbitary == 0)
        game.state_ = &GameState::intro;
    }
}

void Playing::update(Game& game) {
}
```

You can leave some of the method inside the class declaration. Usually it's done if the method is small, would benefit from inlining and doesn't have this kind of circular dependency problem.

Comment: Ok this seems to answer my question confidently! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Move the implementations of the functions out-of-line to *after* the definitions of all classes.

The compiler must see the inherited classes `Playing` and `Introduction` fully before it will know that they inherit from `GameState`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Game;
class Introduction;
class Playing;

class GameState
{
public:

    static Introduction intro;
    static Playing play;

    virtual ~GameState() {std::cout << "an undefined GameState has been destroyed" << std::endl;}
    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) {}
    virtual void update(Game& game) {}

};

class Game
{
public:

    Game()
    {}
    ~Game()
    {}

    virtual void handleinput(int arbitary)
        {
            state_->handleinput(*this, arbitary);
        }

    virtual void update()
        {
            state_->update(*this);
        }

//private: 
    GameState* state_;
};

class Introduction : public GameState
{
public:

    Introduction()  
    {
        std::cout << "constructed Introduction state" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary);

    virtual void update(Game& game) {}
};

class Playing : public GameState
{
public:
    Playing()   {std::cout << "constructed Playing state" << std::endl;}

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary);

    virtual void update(Game& game) {}
};

void Introduction::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
{
    if (arbitary == 1)
        game.state_ = &GameState::play;
}

void Playing::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
{
    if (arbitary == 0)
        game.state_ = &GameState::intro;
}

Introduction GameState::intro;
Playing GameState::play;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Game thisgame;

    return 0;
}
```