# c++ nested classes access

Tags: c++, class, scope, state

Following is a simplified header file detailing three Classes. I want to be able to keep the pointer in my "Game" class private, and allow Introduction to modify it. However, as is, this is not working. As Introduction is a derivative of GameState, I thought I would be able to modify this pointer? Examples had shown that this was possible. I don't really want to move this to the Public space within Game.

```
class Introduction;
class Game;
class GameState;

class GameState
{
    public:

    static Introduction intro;

    virtual ~GameState();
    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary);
    virtual void update(Game& game);

};


class Introduction : public GameState
{
public:

    Introduction();

    virtual void handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary); 

    virtual void update(Game& game);

};


class Game
{
public:

    Game();

    ~Game();

    virtual void handleinput(int arbitary);

    virtual void update();

private:

    GameState* state_;

};
```

The example I was following was here...http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html

EDIT: I am wanting to do something like this...

```
void Introduction::handleinput(Game& game, int arbitary) 
        {
            if (arbitary == 1)
            std::cout << "switching to playing state" << std::endl;
            game.state_ = &GameState::play;
        }
```

EDIT: Thank you for the responses, I think getters and setters are the way to go. And I apologise that the problem was not clear. The *problem* was that I did not understand the implementation I was trying to follow. I still don't understand it, but clearly there are ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Just saying "this is not working" is a very bad problem description. ***How*** is it not working? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You haven't shown how you are using those classes.

Comment: I have added a simple example of how I want to use this. This was shown as being possible in the link.

Comment: Wasn't your question already asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204985/state-pattern-c)?

Comment: I'm afraid it was a different problem. Nevertheless, I appreciate everyones input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions.

## Using Friend class

You can declare [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) classes in your `Game` class.

Something like:

```
class Game {
 public:
  // ...
 private:
  // ...
  friend class Introduction;
};
```

In this way, the class `Introduction` will be able to access to private member of `Game` class and modify it.

---

## Getters And Setters

If you want to preserve *data hiding principle*, you can just provide a public member in order to modify the state of your game.

Here, an example:

```
class Game {
 public:
   void setNewState(GameState* setter) noexcept;
   const GameState* getCurrentState() const noexcept;
   // ...
};
```

Comment: Using **Getters and Setters** should be the first priority solution, as using **Friend Functions** is against the principle of Encapsulation, and whenever possible should be avoided.

Comment: It depend on the design choice. Sometimes *OOP* is just an expensive overload. If those two class are strictly close, *friend* could be a good choice. In general, and your design is OOP, then you're absolutely right! Keep principle of Encapsulation and using getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

How about a getter and an setter?

```
class Game
{
public:

   ....
   GameState * getGameState() const { return state_; }

   void setGameState(GameState * newState) { state_ = newState; }

   ....

private:

    GameState* state_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the pointer Protected and make Game a friend to GameState, to allow Game to access protected members in GameState. 
But as the above comments indicate, its not really clear what you are actually asking.